# using jqGrid addJSONData function with scroll and loadonce option at same time

Tags: jqgrid, scroll

in my  web application i am already using jqgrid since version 3.5.

at my application such as search window, page is comming with no date. after user entering seach parameter when clicking search buton i have done request, grid data and other variable that i needed has come with this ajax request.

so i populate grid with addJSONData metod such as ;

```
var data  = {"page":"1″,"total":0,"records":0,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1-480","1884","BASYAYLA"]},{"id":"2″,"cell":["2-481","1983","SARIVELILER"]}]};

// data variable has return from ajax request.
var mygrid = jQuery("#mygrid")[0];

mygrid.addJSONData(data);
```

Grid populating is problem when you working with big data set. Yesterday i seen new properties called  scroll and loadonce at demo page.

I understand that when i use datatype except than json.

i try to use these metod but i am not able to success.

How could i use addJSONData, scroll and loadonce at same time.

Answer (score 1):

i find solution myself

when you are using loadonce metod it will turn datatype to local so addJSONData metod dont work because datatype is not json.

by following these steps, problem has solved.

i set datatype local to grid dont make first call

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{
    datatype: "local"
});
```

for loading data to grid. i follow these commands;

$("#"+objeId).setGridParam({datatype:'json', loadonce:true});
        mygrid.addJSONData(myjsongrid);
        $("#"+objeId).setGridParam({datatype:'local'});

every thing work fine for me.